# multiple entries of the same transaction in developer menu - Genexus 16

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd, genexus-gam, genexus-dbret

Everytime I delete and then add the transaction `COUNTRY`, it adds a new entry on the developer menu:

[image: 1]

How do I delete or change the way Genexus behave in order to stop creating new items `country` in the menu?

Answer (score 1):

The `developermenu.html` file is generated from the `DeveloperMenu.xml`, and this one gets generated based on the following files:
- `GXHPRO15.<Model#>`  for WebPanels
- `GXTPRO15.<Model#>`  for Transactions
- `GXPPRO15.<Model#>`  for Procedures

In your case you should delete the `GXTPRO15.<Model#>` file and Rebuild your environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for my delay. I deleted the only GXHPRO15 file available, in my case GXHPRO15.002. Now i see the multiple "Country" entries plus this ones:
GX0010
GX0020
GX0040
GX0050
GX00B0
GX00C1

Where else should i look for the file to delete?

thanks.

Comment: Veo que hablas español, así seria mas fácil hacerme entender jaja. Ya borre el archivo que me dijiste, ahora me aparece "country" repetido y los otros accesos también. No tengo idea sinceramente como solucionarlo, generalmente encuentro mucha info en internet de otros temas pero encuentro poco o nada de genexus asi que tengo que preguntar nomas. Tenes idea que otra cosa puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Wich version of GeneXus?
Did you try with **Rebuild ALL**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29793828)